# Python : I used the beautifulsoup. but result value of href is disappeared

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the html

```
<div class="s_write">
    <p style="text-align:left;"></P>
    <div app_paragraph="Dc_App_Img_0" app_editorno="0">
    <img src="http://dcimg6.dcinside.co.kr/viewimage.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&amp;no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f244141456484ebe788e4b1ac8601ef468abc7cad6754f440d9ddbfc0370c7" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:imgPop('http://image.dcinside.com/viewimagePop.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&amp;no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f24452490c8b9fb90ae74e4d6a2435010d29956ad37f400586d9cb','image','fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');"></div>
```

I want to extract

```
http://image.dcinside.com/viewimagePop.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f24452490c8b9fb90ae74e4d6a2435010d29956ad37f400586d9cb
```

So I programmed like this

```
for link in internal.find_all('div',class_="s_write"):
    print (link)
```

But result is

```
<div class="s_write"><p style="text-align:left;"><div app_editorno="0" app_paragraph="Dc_App_Img_0"><img src="http://dcimg6.dcinside.co.kr/viewimage.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&amp;no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f24452490c8a9dbf0ae34e4a6a20370e5a2d9633d5701c48dc23ac"/></p></div>
```

`href` is not the result

What's problem?

Comment: `_internal.find_all('div',class_="s_write"):_`... your are searching for all `div`,  so how can can you would get `href`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue with your code :**

You are searching for dev which will return you only dev block . If you want to find img href you need to searh for img tag.

Following is a rough example to get this done.

```
import bs4 as bs
markup = """<div class="s_write">
    <p style="text-align:left;"></P>
    <div app_paragraph="Dc_App_Img_0" app_editorno="0">
    <img src="http://dcimg6.dcinside.co.kr/viewimage.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&amp;no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f244141456484ebe788e4b1ac8601ef468abc7cad6754f440d9ddbfc0370c7" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:imgPop('http://image.dcinside.com/viewimagePop.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&amp;no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f24452490c8b9fb90ae74e4d6a2435010d29956ad37f400586d9cb','image','fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');"></div>"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")
imglink = soup.find_all("img")[0]
print(imglink.attrs["src"])
```

**Output**

```
http://dcimg6.dcinside.co.kr/viewimage.php?id=2fbcc323e7d334aa51b1d3a240&no=24b0d769e1d32ca73fef84fa11d028318f52c0eeb141bee560297996d466c894cf2d16427672bba3d66d67f244141456484ebe788e4b1ac8601ef468abc7cad6754f440d9ddbfc0370c7
```